# C# MVC EF - Set a foreign key to NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, code-first

I am trying to set a foreign key to "Null".. Using the SQL Management Studio it works fine, but trying it using C#, I am getting a exception:

Exception:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity.

Code:

```
    var entity = _db.AlleBenutzer.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    if (entity != null)
    {
        var abteilungObjekt = _db.AlleAbteilungen.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Abteilungsname == abteilung);
        var etageObjekt = _db.AlleEtagen.Include(p => p.Abteilung).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Etagenname == etage);
        entity.Abteilung = abteilungObjekt;
        entity.Etage = etageObjekt;
        _db.Entry(entity.Abteilung).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.Entry(entity.Etage).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My both models look like that: (cut some pieces)

```
public class Benutzer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Abteilung Abteilung { get; set; }
    public Etage Etage { get; set; }
}

public class Abteilung
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Abteilungsname { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me out? How do I modify my model to be able to make my Foreign Keys nullable? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looking at your code and error message it seems that either abteilungObjekt or etageObjekt is null so that when you use _db.Entry(entity.Abteilung).State or the next statement that is what is causing the error.

Comment: Yeah, right, but it has to be null. I want to set it to null

Answer (score 1):

In your model the ID that is acting as your FK should be an `int?` to make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var entity = _db.AlleBenutzer.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    if (entity != null)
    {
        var abteilungObjekt = _db.AlleAbteilungen.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Abteilungsname == abteilung);
        if (abteilungObjekt != null)
        {
            entity.Abteilung = abteilungObjekt;
            _db.Entry(entity.Abteilung).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        var etageObjekt = _db.AlleEtagen.Include(p => p.Abteilung).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Etagenname == etage);
        if (etageObjekt != null)
        {        
            entity.Etage = etageObjekt;
            _db.Entry(entity.Etage).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        _db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

As it looks like either abteilungObjekt or etageObjekt may be null when you try to assign them to the entity.  You should always perform a null check when using `FirstOrDefault()` on reference types.

Comment: The chance, that they can be null after FirstOrDefault, is exactly, what I want. Not every user (Benutzer) has to have a section (Abteilung), its optionally assignable.

Comment: That code will only change something, if the FK's are not null, but I want to add the null-Value to the database instead of discarding the changes :)